# How to prevent TYPO3 6.x from using original image source?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

When rendering an image, TYPO3 6.x places it in the `_processed_`temp folder, where all temporary files are stored.

UNLESS the desired rendering size is equal to the file's original size. Then it will link to the original source file instead. This sounds economical, but in some cases, this is not desirable.

In my case, I have all source images in a protected directory where access is handled by `naw_securedownloads`. So the `img` tag becomes something like this:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/index.php?eID=tx_nawsecuredl&u=0&g=0&t=1399912827&hash=0a111ac62d806a0ff26649b065f03be674e7d9b3&file=fileadmin/private/images/example.png" />
```

Which is a big performance issue, as the image won't be compressed nor cached properly, it seems.

I have worked around this by specifying a different rendering image size. But no guarantee this won't happen in other places.

So (how) can this "use original if re-rendering isn't necessary" behaviour be turned off and TYPO3 be forced to put all images it uses into the `_processed`folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I can't just comment your question based on missing reputations, I have to give you the hint by writing an answer.

Have you already tried to overwrite the ImageViewHelper? It says: 'Resizes a given image (**if required**) and renders the respective img tag'. Maybe it's possible to always process your images by overwriting the viewhelper.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is there a howto on overwriting Core View VHs? I think I'll post it as a feature request for the core

Comment: In your extension simply create a ImageViewHelper.php (class gets the same name) under Classes/ViewHelpers/. Your class can extend the class \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\ImageViewHelper. In your templates and/or partials in the first line add this: {namespace vh=Vendor\ExtensionName\ViewHelpers}. Now, instead of using <f:image> you use <vh:image>. Thats it of overwriting a viewhelper.

Comment: On https://forge.typo3.org/issues/59067 there's an xclass hack now by rotating the image 360 degrees